# Is grails scaffolding transactional in any way?

Tags: grails, transactions, scaffolding

I looked at `Controller.groovy` source code, and it looks like CRUD operations are not transactional (at least explicitly).

If I'm right, does it mean that dynamic scaffolding should not be used in production as is? Is there a way to make it transactional (i.e. can I modify `Controller.groovy` or whatever?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the scaffolding is not transactional.  This might be because grails and hibernate support data sources that don't support transactions, such as MySQL's MyISAM engine.

You can change it to be transactional as follows:

1. run `grails install-templates`
2. edit `src/templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy`

Grails will use this template for `generate-controller` or whenever it dynamically generates a scaffolding controller.

Comment: While this is technically correct, doing transaction work in a Controller isn't really best practice.  All transactional work should be done in a Service.  Use scaffolding lightly.  Do not put scaffolding code into production.

Comment: I disagree that there's anything inherently bad or not production-ready about scaffolding. By using the scaffolding (I'm not assuming the out-of-the-box, but rather that some modifications have been made). Scaffolding gives you a huge maintainability win and, if anything, _forces_ you to keep your controllers thin.

Comment: Transactions in the service layer is a best practice, but I wouldn't move CRUD operations into a service solely for transactionality.  Also, scaffolding is a powerful way to provide a simple CRUD interface for e.g. administration with a bare minimum of code and effort, and is appropriate for a wide range of applications.

Comment: Putting transactional code in controllers has bit me on more than one occasion so we'll just agree to disagree.